# No route matches [GET] file in asset folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, assets

I know for a fact that the files exist and are readable.

I'm attempting to create a button that downloads a file on click using an `a` tag that points to the file's location. It wasn't working, so I made the `a` tag direct to the file and I then received an error telling me that it couldn't find it.

The files (XML type files) are found (and subsequently parsed and rendered fine) as such: `Dir.glob('app/assets/directory/*')`

Could this be an issue with assets being compiled?

I am in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to be able to access the `app/assets` directly from the browser. When you precompile the assets it copies the assets in `app/assets` into `public/assets` and usually adds a fingerprint. For example:

```
app/assets/images/image.png
```

becomes

```
public/assets/image-0a5440e6975d3b7d5ab8f485e33fd6e5.png
```

Stop your server. Delete the `public/assets` and `tmp/cache/assets` directory if you have them. Precompile the assets `rake assets:precompile`. Start the server. Then check `public/assets` for the specific file you're trying to reference in the `a` tag. So in this case you would navigate to `localhost:3000/assets/image.png`

But it's not a good idea to hardcode the filename for production. You should let Rails do the magic with the embedded tags.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to hardcode the filenames. The link is now working but for some reason only on my local machine, I've tried both development and production mode on the server.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard If you're having a new problem it is best to accept the answer and ask a new question showing the errors. Did you repeat the steps in my answer on your server? And did you try setting `config.assets.compile = true` in `config/environments/production.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

After pre-compiling the assets, file names will be changed and a fingerprint code will be added to the end of the file name. For instance, `app/assets/icon.png` will become `public/assets/icon-10116c180e629f40e8ebe9a856d25d49.png`.

You can achieve the pre-compiled name of the asset files with:

```
asset_path 'icon.png'
```

And for making a link to the file you can use:

```
<%= link_to 'link_title', asset_path('icon.png') %>
```